# Load a div squence into a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to make a dictionary out of this sequence with jquery/javascript?

> key:value

```
<div id="hidden_loaded_deals">
  <div>1:5</div>
  <div>2:5</div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
$('#hidden_loaded_deals > div').text()
```

and the result is:

```
"1:52:5"
```

It looses the separation between the strings in order to push them later into a dictionary.
is there a function out of the box todo that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koolnic's answer is very good, but I would suggest using object literal as a key-value store. Then you can use `for in` syntax for looping the keys.

```
var tmpdict = {};
$('#hidden_loaded_deals > div').each(
    function(){
        var splitted = $(this).text().split(':');
        tmpdict[splitted[0]] = splitted[1];
    }
);

for(var key in tmpdict)
{
    var value = tmpdict[key];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this to convert the text values to an Array:

```
var x = $.makeArray($('#hidden_loaded_deals > div'))
         .map(function(a){return $(a).text();});
//=> x = ['1:5','2:5']
```

or more conservative:

```
var tmpdict = [];
$('#hidden_loaded_deals > div').each(
    function(){
        tmpdict.push($(this).text());
    }
);
//=> tmpdict = ['1:5','2:5']
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work. Iterate over each `div`, parse its text, and update the object ("dictionary").

```
var x = {};
$('#hidden_loaded_deals > div').each(function(index, elem) {
    var l = elem.innerText.split(':');
    x[l[0]] = l[1];
});
console.log(x); // x is {"1": "5", "2": "5"}
```

Comment: It works for me, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/orip/CqYZH/ Is the jsfiddle example working for you? If so, are there other elements under `#hidden_loaded_deals`?